# Move an NSRect with mouse

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

how can I create an NSRect where it is selectable and can be moved around inside a view? Would it be a CGRect or an NSRect to accomplish this? what would I add to:

```
NSRect viewFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Would I first have to make it selectable and then use an NSEvent, or could I have the NSRect origin be equal to my mouse position in an NSTracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSRect and CGRect are just structures that contain the data that defines a rectangle. If you want to draw a rectangle on the screen, you'll need to create a view that draws the rectangle. To move that rectangle, you'll tell the view to draw the rectangle in different locations, or just move the view around.